# Xml node is getting replaced by another

Tags: c#, xml, forms, xmlwriter

I want to write university courses in an xml file and be sorted by   departments. So if I add a course from different departments I will get something like:

```
<Departments>
    <FST_Department>
        <Course_Details>
            <Course_Name >Networking</Course_Name>
            <Course_Code >xx</Course_Code>
        </Course_Details>
    </FST_Department >
    <Medicine_Department>
        <Course_Details>
            <Course_Name >General_Medicine</Course_Name>
            <Course_Code >xxxxxxx</Course_Code>
        </Course_Details>
    </Medicine_Department>
</Departments
```

But instead all my courses go inside the last department I added a course to and the other department 'tags' disapear.Like below.

```
<Departments>
    <Medicine_Department>
        <Course_Details>
            <Course_Name >Networking</Course_Name>
            <Course_Code >xx</Course_Code>
         </Course_Details>
         <Course_Details>
            <Course_Name >General Medicine</Course_Name>
            <Course_Code >xxxxxxx</Course_Code>
        </Course_Details>
    </Medicine_Department>
    </Departments
```

The code to create the xml file .

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
if (!Directory.Exists(path = "E:\\Sorting\\Directory"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path = "E:\\Sorting\\Directory");

if (!File.Exists(path = "E:\\Sorting\\Directory\\Sort.xml"))
{
    XmlTextWriter xW = new XmlTextWriter(path ="E:\\Sorting\\Directory\\Sort.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
    xW.WriteStartElement("Departments");//my root


    xW.WriteEndElement(); // Departments
    xW.Close();
```

This is the code I use to add data to the xml file :

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("E:\\Sorting\\Directory\\Sort.xml");
XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("Departments");
xNode.RemoveAll();


if (combboBox.Text == "FST")
{               
    XmlNode xDepartmentNode = xDoc.CreateElement("FST_Department");

    foreach (Course c in courses)
    {
        XmlNode xCourse_Details = xDoc.CreateElement("Course_Details");

        XmlNode xCode = xDoc.CreateElement("Course_Code");
        xCode.InnerText = c.courseCode;
        xCourse_Details.AppendChild(xCode);
        XmlNode xName = xDoc.CreateElement("Course_Name");
        xName.InnerText = c.courseName;
        xCourse_Details.AppendChild(xName);

        xDepartmentNode.AppendChild(xCourse_Details);
        xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xDepartmentNode);
        xDoc.Save("E:\\Sorting\\Directory\\Sort.xml");
    }
} 
else if(combbobox.Text == "Medicine")
{              
    XmlNode xDepartmentNode = xDoc.CreateElement("Medicine_Department");

    foreach (Course c in courses)
    {

        XmlNode xCourse_Details = xDoc.CreateElement("Course_Details");


        XmlNode xCode = xDoc.CreateElement("Course_Code");
        xCode.InnerText = c.courseCode;
        xCourse_Details.AppendChild(xCode);
        XmlNode xName = xDoc.CreateElement("Course_Name");
        xName.InnerText = c.courseName;
        xCourse_Details.AppendChild(xName);

        xDepartmentNode.AppendChild(xCourse_Details);
        xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xDepartmentNode);
        xDoc.Save("E:\\Sorting\\Directory\\Sort.xml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You clear all departments with this line.  So anything that was there before is wiped from the file:

```
xNode.RemoveAll();
```

Second, with your `foreach` on `courses`, you will add all the courses to that department. Since you neither sort or filter the courses by department, you are getting them all into whatever department `combobox.Text` is selecting.

Comment: Now it works kind of, the courses are in the appropriate department but they are in the order I added them. <fst></fst><medicine></medicine><medicine></medicine>

Comment: @user3645080 Yep, because you are not sorting them. You simply append them to the end of the file.  You'll have to come up with an Insert method instead of the append you are using.

Comment: @user3645080 And if you want to use the existing medicine for additional medicine courses, then you need to search for an existing one first, then if not found, create one.

Answer (score 0):

Scrap it and use XML Serialization lol

Departments Class

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Serializer
{
    public class Departments
    {
        public FST_Department FST_Department { get; set; }
        public Medicine_Department Medicine_Department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

FST_Department Class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Serializer
{
    public class FST_Department
    {
        public List<Course> Course_Details { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Medicine_Department Class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Serializer
{
    public class Medicine_Department
    {
        public List<Course> Course_Details { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Course Class

```
namespace Serializer
{
    public class Course
    {
        public string Course_Name { get; set; }
        public string Course_Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Read and write serialized xml

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Serializer
{
    class XMLManager
    {
        private const string configFileName = "Departments.xml";

        public static Departments Read()
        {
            XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Departments));
            using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(Global.AppRoot,      configFileName)))
            {
                return reader.Deserialize(file) as Departments;
            }
        }

        public static void Write(Departments settings)
        {
            XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Departments));
            using (FileStream file = File.Create(Path.Combine(Global.AppRoot, configFileName)))
            {
                writer.Serialize(file, settings);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
        Departments depart = new Departments();
        FST_Department fst = new FST_Department();
        fst.Course_Details = new List<Course>();

        Course course = new Course();
        course.Course_Code = "1";
        course.Course_Name = "Test 1";

        fst.Course_Details.Add(course);
        course = new Course();
        course.Course_Code = "2";
        course.Course_Name = "Test2";
        fst.Course_Details.Add(course);
        depart.FST_Department = fst;

        Medicine_Department med = new Medicine_Department();
        med.Course_Details = new List<Course>();

        course = new Course();
        course.Course_Code = "3";
        course.Course_Name = "Test 3";
        med.Course_Details.Add(course);
        depart.Medicine_Department = med;

        //put it all in some kind of order in case things were added out of order
        depart.FST_Department.Course_Details.OrderBy(c => c.Course_Code);
        depart.Medicine_Department.Course_Details.OrderBy(c => c.Course_Code);

        XMLManager.Write(depart);
```

XML File Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Departments xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <FST_Department>
    <Course_Details>
      <Course>
        <Course_Name>Test 1</Course_Name>
        <Course_Code>1</Course_Code>
      </Course>
      <Course>
        <Course_Name>Test2</Course_Name>
        <Course_Code>2</Course_Code>
      </Course>
    </Course_Details>
  </FST_Department>
  <Medicine_Department>
    <Course_Details>
      <Course>
        <Course_Name>Test 3</Course_Name>
        <Course_Code>3</Course_Code>
      </Course>
    </Course_Details>
  </Medicine_Department>
</Departments>
```

Comment: Used the Serializer class. Works fine if I run it and and add stuff to xml but  when I open it again toupdate the xml file everything is being written from scratch like it opens a 'new' xml file.

Comment: Can you clarify just a little more. When you deserialize the XML you will have Departments containing everything in the XML. You add/remove/change items. When you serialize it back to a file then if will write it back with everything contained in it.